# how do I store object on local database on xcode swift

Tags: swift, database, xcode, storage

I've created a class in my application I'm creating multiple instance/objects of this class, and I want to be able to create these objects and be store them in local storage and to be able to initialize these objects once the application restarts again. I want to know that if there is anyways which I am able to efficiently and effectively store these objects, or store the values in the object and be able to initialize them again once the program starts.

```
//
//  MealPlan.swift
//  IA
//
//  Created by Ian Dong on 8/25/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Ian Dong. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

struct MealPlan {
    
    var ingerdientList: [IngerdientCost] = [];
    var k: Int = 0;
    var serving : Int
    var cost : [IngerdientCost] = [];
    var name : String;
    
    init ( size: Int, name: String){
        self.serving = size;
        self.name = name;
    }
    mutating func addIngerdient (newIngerdient: IngerdientCost){
        ingerdientList.insert(newIngerdient, at: k);
        k = k+1;
    }
    mutating func removeINgerdient(theIngerdient: IngerdientCost)
    {
        var c: Int = 0;
        while theIngerdient.amount != ingerdientList[c].amount && c <= k
        {
            c=c+1;
        }
        ingerdientList.remove(at: c);
        k=k-1;
    }
    mutating func getCost() -> Array<IngerdientCost>
    {
        var c: Int = 0;
        while c <= ingerdientList.count
        {
            cost[c].ingerdientName = ingerdientList[c].ingerdientName;
            cost[c].amount = ingerdientList[c].amount * Double(serving);
            c = c+1;
        }
        return cost;
    }
    mutating func setServing( serv: Int)
    {
        self.serving = serv;
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct IngerdientCost{
    
    init(Name: Ingerdient, Amount: Double )
    {
        self.amount = Amount;
        self.ingerdientName = Name;
    }
    
    var ingerdientName: Ingerdient;
    var amount: Double;
    
}
```

```
//
//  Ingerident.swift
//  IA
//
//  Created by Ian Dong on 8/25/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Ian Dong. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

struct Ingerdient {
    var name: String;
      var amount: Double;
    
    init (Name:String, Amount:Double)
    {
        self.name = Name;
        self.amount = Amount;
    }
   
    mutating func setname (newname :String)
    {
        self.name = newname;
    }
    
    mutating func setamount (newamount : Double)
    {
        self.amount = newamount;
    }
    
    func getName() -> String
    {
        return self.name
    }
    func getAmount() -> Double
    {
        return self.amount
    }
    
}

struct IngerdientList {
    
    var completeList: [Ingerdient] = [];
}
```

Comment: Read about CoreData. It is the default way to store objects in the apple environment. It takes time to get used to and sometimes it's a bitch but there is no way around it i guess.

Comment: But you had a database in your earlier questions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using CoreData but it can be a bit hard sometimes. You could try taking a look at Realm, it's a kinda "pain-free" alternative to CoreData. CoreData is by Apple so in the long term, it would probably be more reliable. But Realm, in my opinion, has a much more intuitive way to persist data because of the way the objects are organized. Both Realm and CoreData are equally powerful, however I have heard that Realm is faster than CoreData when querying.

Core Data: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata

Realm: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: Sorry about that, I’m usually on the other end of things. I’ll make the edits!